# How do I get the name and uuid to display when the form is submitted in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, components, onsubmit

I'm trying to create a web application that will have an entry field to collect a name, a button to submit, and an area to display a result message. I'm using a form styled with bootstrap and when using the "onSubmit" in the form, it is not doing anything, however if I change the form to "onClick", it displays a Name:UUID, which is exactly the output I want.
[React On Submit picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ut7Dj.jpg)
[React On Click picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4dXSt.jpg)
Can someone please help me understand why this is happening and how to fix it? **How do I get the name and uuid to display when the form is submitted?** Please see my code and screenshots below:

```
...
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css";
import { v4 as uuidv4 } from 'uuid';
import "./form.css";

function Form() {
    const [name, setName] = useState("");
    const [uuid, setUuid] = useState("");
  
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      // Preventing the default behavior of the form submit
      e.preventDefault();
  
      // Getting the value and name of the input which triggered the change
      const { target } = e;
      const inputType = target.name;
      const inputValue = target.value;
  
      // use input to save
        if (inputType === "name") {
            setName(inputValue);
            setUuid(uuidv4());
            }
            e.preventDefault();
    };

    return (
        <div className="container">
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
            <div className="row instructions text-left">
            <div className=" col-sm-2 d-flex justify-content-between"></div>
            <div className=" col-sm-10 d-flex justify-content-between">
                <label>Please enter your name below:</label>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div className="row">
            <div className="col-sm-2 label-font">
                <label className="label-font name" value="name">
                Name:
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className="col-sm-5">
                <div className="row">
                <input
                    name="name"
                    type="name"
                    className="form-control"
                    placeholder="Type your name here (with no spaces)"
                ></input>
                </div>
                <div className="row">
                <button
                    type="submit"
                    className="btn-success btn-lg"
                >
                    Submit
                </button>
                </div>
            </div>
            </div>
        </form>
        <div className="row">
            <div className=" col-sm-2 label-font">
                <label className="label-font">
                Result:
                </label>
            </div>
            <div className=" col-sm-10 result-output">
                <label className="result-output">
                {name}: {uuid}
                </label>
            </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
    }


  export default Form;
...
```

Comment: Your event is for the whole form, not for the input field. Try to put a console.log or debug `e.target`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your event is for the whole form, not for the input field.

Here is the way with minimal changes of your code:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
      // Preventing the default behavior of the form submit
      e.preventDefault();
  
      // Getting the value and name of the input which triggered the change
      const inputValue = e.target.name.value;
  
      // use input to save
      setName(inputValue);
      setUuid(uuidv4());
    };
```

A link to the working playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-austin-4w9iv?file=/src/App.js